# Can $C^1$ mappings with derivative of low rank be approximated by smooth maps?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, real-analysis, differential-topology, approximation-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Asked once on SE-mathematics.

Let $U$ be an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $m\in\mathbb{N}$, $1\leq m<n$ and let
$$\mathcal{C}^k_{\leq m}(U,\mathbb{R}^n):=\lbrace g\in\mathcal{C}^k(U,\mathbb{R}^n)\mid\dim \operatorname{im} Df(x)\leq m\:\forall x\in U\rbrace,$$
where $\mathcal{C}^k(U,\mathbb{R}^n)$ mean $k-$times continuously differentiable mappings from U to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Is it true that 
$$\mathcal{C}^\infty_{\leq m}(U,\mathbb{R}^n)\overset{\text{dense}}{\subset}\mathcal{C}^1_{\leq m}(U,\mathbb{R}^n),$$
with the usual $\left(\mathcal{C}^1,d(\cdot,\cdot)_{\mathcal{C}^1}\right)$ distance  $$d(f,g)_{\mathcal{C}^1}=\sup\limits_{x\in U}\left|f(x)-g(x)\right|+
\sup\limits_{x\in U}\left\|Df(x)-Dg(x)\right\|.$$

$|\cdot|$ is length of a vector from $\mathbb{R}^n$ and
$\|\cdot\|$ is length of vector from $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$.
Link to mathSE question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1876303/357336

Comment: You should link to your question on MSE.

Comment: It seems that the answer is ``No'' due to the Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem and Sard Theorem.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Thank you for the comment! Do you want to use BFPT to mapping with rank restriction and assume that domain U is a ball or apply this theorem to a ball in function space some transformation of mappings ? Would you please elaborate.

Comment: @Polatucha  By Sard Theorem, any differentiable map $f:U\to R^n$ whose differential $Df$ has rank $<n$ at each point $x\in U$ has image $f(U)$ of zero Lebesgue measure. On the other hand, BFPT implies that any map $f:U\to R^n$ which is sufficiently close to the identity in $C^0$-topology has image $f(U)$ with non-empty interior. These two facts imply that maps with differentials of small rank cannot be dense in $C^\infty(U,R^n)$ even in the $C^0$-topology.

Comment: This is true, but I do not understand how not-density of small rank in whole $\mathcal{C}^\infty(U,\mathbb{R}^n)$ imply non-density for  the subset $\mathcal{C}^1_{\leq m}(U,\mathbb{R}^n)$. 
As far as I understand identity mapping is far away from any map from the set I am interested in i.e.
 $$d_{\mathcal{C}^1}(\text{id},\mathcal{C}^1_{\leq m}(U,\mathbb{R}^n))>c$$ for some positive constant $c$ depending probably on the dimension $n$.

Comment: Moreover, this is also true that mappings from $\mathcal{C}^1_{\leq m}(U,\mathbb{R}^n)$ can have much more "measure" in the image than smooth maps.

Comment: The powered up Sard theorem 3.4.3 from Federers book "Geometric measure theory" tells us that that the image under $f$ of the whole set U (it is equal to the set where $r(Df)\leq m$ since $f\in\mathcal{C}^1_{\leq m}(U,\mathbb{R}^n)$) can have positive $s-$dimensional Hausdroff measure for any $s<n$ because the optimal result is that $$\mathcal{H}^n(\lbrace x\:\vert\: dim\:im Df(x)\leq m\rbrace)=0$$ where $n=m-(n-m)/k$ and $k$ is how many times map $f$ is continuously differentiable.

Comment: From this we have:

Comment: Let $U\overset{\text{open}}{\subset}\mathbb{R}^5$ and $f\in\mathcal{C}^1_{\leq 3}(U,\mathbb{R}^5)$ such that $\mathcal{H}^4(f(U))>0$. Now any smooth map with the same rank restriction, that is $f_\epsilon\in \mathcal{C}^\infty_{\leq 3}(U,\mathbb{R}^5)$ has at most $\mathcal{H}^m$ positive measure. And we can think that it is a problem because we have to approximate a set of dimension 4 by a set of dimension at most 3, but it is not clear to me that one can not do it because in examples images of such $f's$ are not a valid 4 manifolds but some kind of Cantor sets.

Comment: @TarasBanakh The answer is in the negative, see below.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz I think it is done, green "ptaszek" marked. In the middle of May i should speak with Paweł about yor joint work, then this acceptance may become legally valid.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**There is a counterexample.**

**Example.** There is $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^5,\mathbb{R}^5)$ with ${\rm rank}\, Df\leq 3$ that cannot be approximated in the supremum norm by mappings 
$g\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^5,\mathbb{R}^5)$ satisfying ${\rm rank}\, Dg\leq 3$.

**Example.** *There is $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^7,\mathbb{R}^7)$, ${\rm rank}\, Df\leq 4$, that cannot be approximated in the supremum norm by mappings
$g\in C^3(\mathbb{R}^7,\mathbb{R}^7)$ satisfying ${\rm rank}\, Dg\leq 4$.*

Both examples are special cases of the following result proved in [1]:

> **Theorem.** *Suppose that $m+1\leq k<2m-1$, $\ell\geq k+1$, $r\geq m+1$, and the homotopy group $\pi_k(S^m)$ is non-trivial.  Then there
>   is a map $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^\ell, \mathbb{R}^r)$ with ${\rm rank}\,
>  Df\leq m $ in $\mathbb{R}^\ell$ that cannot be approximated by maps of
>   class $ C^{k-m+1}$.*

You can find infinitely many more examples.

[1] **P. Goldstein, P. Hajłasz,** [$C^1$ mappings in $\mathbb{R}^5$ with derivative of rank at most $3$ cannot be uniformly approximated by $C^2$ mappings with derivative of rank at most $3$.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.08289) . *J. Math. Anal. Appl.* 468 (2018), 1108–1114.
(arXiv:1804.08289).